# A. Einstein, "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", page 6. Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity

[image]

Can somebody please tell me what Mr Einstein has done in that step when he assumes x to be infinetisimal and kinda differentiates the function described in previous step. I am banging my head on this since time and damn I don't have any instructor to myself. Pleasee help!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. It might be helpful if you could include an image of that section of the paper, or transcribe the section you are confused about.

Comment: See the second algorithm, I'm not getting how he did this.

Comment: For your help, K is the stationary system with coordinates described by x,y,z,t. k is the system moving relative to K with a positive v velocity in x direction and has the system of coordinates described by the greek letters. It might be possible that Einstein would have used the same symbols in more than one context but that's how far I do know about what I have inferred from the paper. Good luck with the maths.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302517/84967

Comment: No, in that post he claims he knows already how to do it using differentials. He asks about the Fourier transforms. I wish to know how eintein did solve the equation 1 to get equation 2 by using any calculus. Please reconsider.

Comment: Just got the answer, its a Taylor expansion. Thanks for the help efforts guys!

Comment: Hi @HannibalLecter, I got stuck with the sasme exact issue. You say that you got the answer and that it is a Taylor expansion. Could you please give further information or the detailed steps to achieve the result? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry @IagoRodríguez-Quintana I do not know how to type the mathematics here but it goes somewhat by the means of functional expansion, the tailor expansion as I have written. As far as I remember the same thing is written quite appreciably over wikipedia in the "derivations" column of the article lorentz transformation. The same is also available if you type "tailor expansion in lorentz transformation" over google. If you still feel trouble with the math, then there is a very good lecture on special relativity on youtube by Yale University's online courses; give it a try. Good day!

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302517/taylor-series-in-einsteins-on-the-electrodynamics-of-moving-bodies?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Here you go, you are welcome.

Comment: @HannibalLecter thank you very much for useful hints. Best regards.