# Derivation of a partial derivative equation by Albert Einstein in Special Theory of Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, differentiation, calculus

I was reading Albert Einstein's "*On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies*". In section "*Kinematical Part*", on $3 (*Theory of the transformation of coordinates and times from a stationary system to another system in uniform motion of translation relates to the former*), I get the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\tfrac12\left[\tau(0,0,0,t)+\tau\left(0,0,0,t+\dfrac{x'}{c-v}+\dfrac{x'}{c+v}\right)\right] = \tau\left(x',0,0,t+\dfrac{x'}{c-v}\right)
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}

From the above equation, Einstein derived the following equation immediately,

\begin{equation}
\tfrac12\left(\dfrac{1}{c-v}+\dfrac{1}{c+v}\right)\dfrac{\partial\tau}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial\tau}{\partial x'}+\dfrac{1}{c-v}\dfrac{\partial\tau}{\partial t}
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}

Einstein only mentioned this line before stating the equation that "*Hence, if x' be chosen infinitesimally small*". But I could not derive the equation \eqref{02} using partial derivatives on both sides of equation \eqref{01}.

Please provide some guidance.

Comment: I saw same question with answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302517/taylor-series-in-einsteins-on-the-electrodynamics-of-moving-bodies?noredirect=1&lq=1 . The accepted answer does not provide how you can get 2 from 1